# Getting from values in python from Html without page reload

Tags: javascript, html, python-3.x

In below code I am tring to get textarea data and using it in python code and showing output in  `#result-container` container.
But when I was using the html form tag with  `button type="submit"` getting the values but it's on getting print in result container due to html deafult page reload function.

I tried using some other method like using fetch method and preventDefault() but it's not working as expected.

What i want is whenever a form submit the value should pass into backend in "/process_text"

Any help!

Python Code

```
@app.route('/process_text', methods=['POST'])
def process_text():
    global uploaded_data
    if request.method == 'POST':
        text = request.form.get('text')   # Get the value of the 'text' textarea

        # Check if the text is a query for generating a graph
        if text != None:
            if text.startswith('graph') or text.startswith('plot'):
                query = text[5:]  # Remove the 'graph' prefix from the query

                if "bar" in query.lower():
                    result = generate_bar_chart(uploaded_data, query)
                elif "line" in query.lower():
                    result = generate_line_chart(uploaded_data, query)
                elif "pie" in query.lower():
                    result = generate_pie_chart(uploaded_data, query)
                else:
                    print("Invalid plot type. Please specify 'bar', 'line', or 'pie'.")

                return render_template('data.html', data=uploaded_data.to_html(), result=result)
            else:
                result = chat_with_file(uploaded_data, text)
        else:
            result = "please give some input"

            return render_template('data.html', data=uploaded_data.to_html(), result=result)

    return render_template('data.html', data=uploaded_data.to_html())
```

HTML Code

```
 <div class="textarea-container">
                <h3>Enter your Text:</h3>
                <div class="textarea-container">
                    <h3>Enter your Text:</h3>
                    <form action="/process_text" method="POST" id="text-form">
                        <textarea placeholder="Enter text here" name="text" id="text-input"></textarea>
                        <a href="#" id="record-button" class="submit-button">Record</a>
                        <a href="#" id="stop-button" class="submit-button">Stop</a>
                        <button id="submit-button" class="submit-button" type="submit">Submit</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div id="result-container" class="result-container">
                    <h3>Result:</h3>
                    <div id="result">
                        {{ result }}

                    </div>
                </div>
          </div>
```